# Very slow response from localhost when pinging

Tags: networking, gentoo, ping

Networking is working fine on my Gentoo machine. One connection is made, everything works fine with normal speed. But it is slow to wake-up; starting up connection is taking time. Even pinging localhost takes ages (about 5 seconds).

Any ideas how to make this fast?

Output of some commands:

```
ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.107.105.13  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.107.111.255
    inet6 fe80::e269:95ff:fe24:8d3a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether e0:69:95:24:8d:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1071380  bytes 978317595 (932.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1979  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 310432  bytes 30846997 (29.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xfe400000-fe420000  

ping -c 5 localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from Calvin (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
64 bytes from Calvin (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from Calvin (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from Calvin (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from Calvin (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms

--- localhost ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.017/0.028/0.033/0.005 ms

ping -c 5 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.018/0.027/0.034/0.008 ms
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ping -c 5 localhost`?  Do you still get a delay when you do `ping 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @Dilawar Please add `ifconfig` output in your question

Comment: @Flup Add the output. You suspicion was right. Localhost and 127.0.0.1 are giving different response time.

Comment: @RahulPatil Added ifconfig output.

Comment: You are pinging it 5 times. One ping = one second. Five pings = five seconds. Please clarify what you mean by "wake-up" and "starting connection". What is taking time? Once *which* connection has been made? In all my exp. `ifconfig eth0 10.3.0.6 up` or DHCP is instantaneous. Doing pppoe takes some seconds, though... Your responses are < 100 ms! What do you mean *very slow* ?!

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин It takes 5 seconds before very first line is printed on console by `ping localhost`. While `ping 127.0.0.1` starts printing its response within a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are giving different response times, this is a name resolution problem.  Check `/etc/resolv.conf` to make sure that it contains the correct addresses for your nameservers.  If you're not sure of the right addresses, you could try

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

It's slightly odd that `localhost` doesn't resolve from an entry in `/etc/hosts`, so you may want to check that it contains a line that looks something like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Comment: Added line in `/etc/hosts` and it is fine now. Thanks.

Comment: as I see `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` giving almost the same time: `0.028` and `0.027`